# Using .DXF Arc or Circle accurately in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, ogr, dxf

I need to use a .DXF in either QGIS or ArcGIS.

However, if an Arc occurs in a .DXF drawing and if this file is opened in QGIS, I noticed that the geometry of the Arc is simplified. I did a test:

- draw circles in LibreCAD and save as .DXF (I uploaded it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9umy2nuv82yf001/circle.dxf?dl=0))
- open in QGIS
- convert to shapefile
- edit shape

The circles, regardless of their size are approximated by 90 segments, so a 4-degree long circle segment is represented by a straight line. In my application this causes significant deviations (>25cm) in a canal design project...

I tried the same in ArcGIS. There, the simplification depends on the circle size - small circles have fewer segments, larger circles have more. So, in my case (for the kilometer long radius in canal bends) ArcGIS seems like the better choice.

As a side note: In ArcGIS the Arc of the .DXF is not simplified when visualized - the display of the .DXF seems correct when overlying with the exported shapefile. Within ArcGIS this would make at least snapping and digitization in higher accuracy possible.

I am a beginner in using .DXF files in GIS, but I feel this should be a popular problem. Though, after searching for a while I could not find a hint anywhere. I still fear I may miss something obvious... In case not, does anybody have a workaround for this?

I am using QGIS 2.10 (GDAL 1.11.2) and ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: Have you tried converting your DXF to a file geodatabase feature class. File geodatabases, unlike shapefiles, support true curves.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the arc is maintained! But since I need to edit the arc in GIS (split, add attributes) this is not an option for me.

Comment: You should be able to use [Densify (Editing)](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//001v00000003000000) to put in as many vertices as you want to do that editing.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you very much. Actually - this is the method I will end up using because it fully keeps the arc accuracy! This would be my accepted answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you convert your DXF to a file geodatabase feature class which, unlike shapefiles, will support true curves.

You should be able to use [Densify (Editing)](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//001v00000003000000) to put in as many vertices as you want to use during any subsequent editing.

Comment: As written in the discussion to the question, this is my accepted answer because it fully keeps the accuracy of the arc.

Answer (score 2):

You must probably convert dxf into shapefile or some other format with ogr2ogr and set smaller stepsize as documented in http://www.gdal.org/drv_dxf.html:

> The approximation of arcs, ellipses, circles and rounded polylines as
>   linestrings is done by splitting the arcs into subarcs of no more than
>   a threshhold angle. This angle is the OGR_ARC_STEPSIZE. This defaults
>   to four degrees, but may be overridden by setting the configuration
>   variable OGR_ARC_STEPSIZE.

The syntax is to add into ogr2ogr command `--config OGR_ARC_STEPSIZE=2`

If your QGIS is using GDAL 2.0 or higher it might be able to read arc directly from GML or PostGIS but still not from DXF https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc49_curve_geometries.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for exactly something like this to set user defined accuracy thresholds. Though the ogr --config syntax (GDAL 1.11.2) is without the '=': 
`ogr2ogr.exe -f "ESRI Shapefile" circle1.shp circle.dxf --config OGR_ARC_STEPSIZE 1`